# Switching to empty window handle (Selenium webdriver)

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have this problem with window handles. I click on a button and expect a popup window to appear, but i'm not sure if it pops up. I print out all window handles before switching, [u'{7f8728c1-75db-4899-b4d1-63af134ee2fc}', u'']. I switch to the list[-1] that means u'' in this case. After switching I print out the current window handle and I get the answer {7f8728c1-75db-4899-b4d1-63af134ee2fc}

Two questions arises here:
1- what is an empty window handle u''?
2- Did I switch to u'' and failed and switched back to main window or selenium can't switch to empty handle and chooses to switch to main window?

Thanks in advance

Comment: add screenshot please.

Comment: Screenshot doesn't give any help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its a alert?

`driver.getWindowHandles()` - prints all windows that are enable in this session, if there is only 1 string '{7f8728c1-75db-4899-b4d1-63af134ee2fc} then this is your current window and there are no more windows. Try `driver.switchTo().alert().accept();`

Comment: So u' ' is in fact an alert? There are actually two strings the one you mentioned and the the empty string u' ' and i specify the last handle in the list to switch to, in this case u' '

If I add a sleep I don't see this issue anymore

Comment: when it's opening window add Thread.Sleep(5000) 5 seconds and print out driver.getWindowHandles(), problem is i never saw empty window string )

Comment: Do you know what is the empty string might be? I don't want to solve this issue with a sleep as I want to optimize my test scripts. I do more than 1000 window switching every night and if adding 5 seconds sleep that will slow down my tests.

Comment: I don't know, sorry. Add scrrenshot of your desktop, this will help